# App UI getting changed on dark mode being turned on

Tags: android, user-interface, mode

I'm developing an app which is working fine. The only problem my app is facing is that, once I turn my system's dark mode "on" the entire interface of the app is getting destroyed. Like all the button color gets changed to default including the textview, etc. I'm pretty sure you got what I'm talking about.

Would really appreciate if anyone could help me on what to do so that my app adapts to the mode.

Comment: What is the problem though? The app getting destroyed/re-created?

Comment: The entire UI gets changed to default. For eg, all the buttons gets changed to PRIMARY BLUE color (default). Any idea what can I do?

Comment: Post a theme you are using. (You might be using  `.DayNight` which does that automatically.)